# XAMPP Apache 2.4 service not starting

Tags: xampp, apache2, windows-10

```
OS: Windows 10
XAMPP xampp-win32-7.1.7-0-VC14-installer
```

I believe Apache 2.4 was installed on this machine, in a folder called c:\localhost\bin\httpd

I installed XAMPP, and when the installion was finished, and I clicked on start, I got the following error message:

```
5:09:46 AM  [Apache]    Apache Service detected with wrong path
5:09:46 AM  [Apache]    Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
5:09:46 AM  [Apache]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
5:09:46 AM  [Apache]    Found Path: "C:\localhost\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

I checked, and there is c:\localhost folder. This folder has been deleted.

How do I handle this error message? I checked the running programs/services and there is no Apache 2.4 running

Comment: force stop your running apache and start the xampp again.

Comment: force stop it? how? It's not in the list of running programs/services, and the folder localhost has been deleted. I have also rebooted my computer

Comment: from task manager? right-click on process/service and stop it

Comment: Did you read the "it's not in the list of programs/services" part of my question/comment?

Comment: No, I read: `How do I handle this error message? I checked the running programs/services and there is Apache 2.4 running`

Comment: Edited. It's not there. The c:\localhost folder is not there. The computer has been rebooted.

Comment: did you install XAMPP after you deleted the `localhost` folder or before? If you deleted the folder after installing, try to reinstall XAMPP

Comment: localhost folder was deleted before installing xampp, and I un-installed xampp and re-installed it